# Wordpress Elementor Migration

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm creating a Wordpress website for a client, which I built on my own server. My client has another company do the migration to their own servers but we had an issue. Elementor stopped working:

- I can't access to page builder, the_content() is not called, but I checked our files and they are not different from the original ones on my server.
- Almost all CSS is missing after CSS regeneration (Error 404).
- Some pages load the wrong image, from the default Wordpress media root instead of the Elementor one.

I've been trying to fix it for 2 days now, can't seem to find the problem.
What I've tried:

- URL replacement using the Elementor Tool.
- Checked EVERY files manually.
- Regenerated the CSS a dozen time but never fixed the CSS issue.

Edit: I found this in the logs

```
PHP: 2020-07-27 20:04:30 [warning X 2][/srv/xxx/prod/xxx/scv2/php5/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/elementor/modules/safe-mode/module.php::107] rmdir(/srv/xxx/prod/xxx/scv2/php5/htdocs/wp-content/mu-plugins): No such file or directory [array (
  'trace' => '
#0: Elementor\Core\Logger\Manager -> shutdown()
',
)]
```

I'd also like to mention that I have ZERO access to the FTP of the new server, I can only access the Wordpress Admin. I can't modify the .php files either. Hopefully someone can give me a hint on how to fix everything.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would Elementor want to delete the mu-plugins folder? That doesn’t look right.

Comment: But I think you’re going to have to get filesystem access, SSH or FTP, to the new server to debug some of this. You might also to ask Elementor directly for help with their plugin not working.

Comment: I'm not sure. It's the first time I've Elementor but I agree it wouldn't make sense for the plugin to delete a folder. I have requested the FTP access to the server but the people but the company in charge of the hosting is quite "hostile". They insist and handling the server themselves and that I'm the one fixing the issue.

Comment: This is a common issue I faced, but never found the actual solution that works everywhere, I usually reinstall the backup/re-migrating, I use duplicator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Earid, I'll ask the hosting company to do it. Hopefully this will fix it. I'll post an update once it's done.

Comment: If your site works without any problem on your server, I think you should  backup the site by this plugin ( Duplicator – WordPress Migration Plugin) and upload it on client's server